# How to define a child object based upon a parent object?

Tags: objective-c, oop, parent-child

this is a general question. I can divide my questions into two :

I have a class ChildClass that herits from ParentClass.

- ParentClass has many attributes and methods.
- ChildClass has a few new methods and a few new attributes.

1) I would like to define a `initFromParentClass` method, whose signature would be

```
       - (id) initFromParentClass:(ParentClass)anObjectFromTheParentClass
```

which would create a new instance of `ChildClass`, based upon `anObjectFromTheParentClass` — that is, all the attributes of the new instance are "copied" from the ones of the "parent instanc".

2) Can these two parent/child objects be dynamically linked ? Ie : if the parent changes, the child changes ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One familiar idiom is to treat let the child class delegate existing methods to an instance of the parent:

```
 @implementation ChildClass
 @property (nonatomic, strong) ParentClass *obj;
 - (void) mill
 {
      [obj mill];
 }

 - (NSInteger) count
 {
       return [obj count];
 }
```

This can be tedious and hard to maintain if ParentClass has a broad and rapidly-changing API.  In that case, you might not want to inherit at all, but rather to extract a common interface from ParentClass and ChildClass, and perhaps let instances of ChildClass observe changes to the object from which they were initialized.